# Plugin create pages and use templates

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, page-template

I have a plugin that is creating a few pages and I want to use the custom templates I made for those specific pages. The pages a creating fine and even one of the templates is working but the other isnt. I will mark it but here is the code:

```
function ch_register_pages() {

    $ch_register_page_title = 'CH';
    $ch_register_page_check = get_page_by_title($ch_register_page_title);
    $ch_register_page = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_title' => $ch_register_page_title,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_slug' => 'CH'
    );


    wp_insert_post($ch_register_page);

    $ch_parent = get_page_by_path('CH');
    $ch_parent_id = $ch_parent->ID;


    $ch_register_page_thankyou_title = 'CH Thank-You';
    $ch_register_page_thankyou_check = get_page_by_title($ch_register_page_thankyou_title);
    $ch_register_page_thankyou = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_title' => $ch_register_page_thankyou_title,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_slug' => 'CH-Thank-you',
        'post_parent' => $ch_parent_id
    );

    wp_insert_post($ch_register_page_thankyou);

}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'ch_register_pages' );


/*
 *  Add page templates to pages 
 *
*/


function ch_register_page_thanks_template() { ////////////////<-------------Doesnt work

     if ( is_page( 'CH-Thank-you' ) ) {//change this to match slug
        $page_thankyou_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/page-ch-thank-you.php';

    }

    return $page_thankyou_template;
}

add_filter( 'page_template', 'ch_register_page_thanks_template' );

function ch_register_page_template() {////////////////<-------------Works

    if ( is_page( 'CH' ) ) { //change this to match slug
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/page-ch.php';
    }

    return $page_template;

}

add_filter( 'page_template', 'ch_register_page_template' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it. It kind of makes sense but doesnt really. The one template wasnt working becuase I was looking for just the slug. Since its a child of the other page I needed to add it in the `is_page` statement. This worked (I also just did it all in one function):

```
function ch_register_page_template($page_template;) {////////////////<-------------Works

    if ( is_page( 'CH' ) ) { //change this to match slug
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/page-ch.php';
        return $page_template;
    }

    if ( is_page( 'CH/CH-Thank-you' ) ) {//change this to match slug
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/page-ch-thank-you.php';
        return $page_template;

    }

    return $page_template;

}

add_filter( 'page_template', 'ch_register_page_template' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your filters return nothing if the conditional doesn't match, so if the first one matches, it's broken by the one that runs after it.

Remember that filters are dealing with some sort of value that is passed through them. Your filters should pass back the unaltered template that was passed to them as function argument if the conditional doesn't match.

```
function ch_register_page_template( $page_template ) {

    if ( is_page( 'CH' ) ) { //change this to match slug
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/page-ch.php';
    }

    return $page_template;

}
add_filter( 'page_template', 'ch_register_page_template' );
```

Comment: I figured out the answer I just posted. The is_page needed to be full path with parent for it to return the template.

Comment: your code is still wrong though, and will break templates on other pages.

Comment: I get what you are saying. So I should return the $page_template un altered outside of the if statements at the end correct?

Comment: yes, note the addition of `$page_template` as function argument in `ch_register_page_template( $page_template )`, which gets returned in all cases.

Comment: I edit my answer. Seems to be working and not breaking pages. Good call, that would not be good to break other peoples pages templates